# How to Iterate through a Java Arraylist one at a time

Tags: java, android

How can I get to iterate through this ArrayList algorithm so that I can change the background of an imageView every time I input a code... E.g. Code = "123456" | Background_1 shows, Code = "123456" | Background_2 shows ...

```
    enter = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.enter);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    punch_back_1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    punch_back_2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    punch_back_3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
    punch_back_4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
    final ArrayList<ImageView> array_image = new ArrayList<>();
    array_image.add(punch_back_1);
    array_image.add(punch_back_2);
    array_image.add(punch_back_3);
    array_image.add(punch_back_4);
    enter.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                String code = input.getText().toString();
                int i = 0;
                if (code.equals("123456")) {
                    i++;
                    array_image.get(i).setImageResource(R.drawable.punch_front);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Awarded 1 new punch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                input.setText(" ");
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

I've tried this both:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{

if (code.equals("123456"))
{
   array_image.get(i).setImageResource(R.drawable.punch_front);
   Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Awarded 1 new punch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}


int i = 0;
while (i < i)
{
   array_image.get(i).setImageResource(R.drawable.punch_front);
   Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Awarded 1 new punch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
i++;
}
```

Which, if I am not mistaken does the same thing.

The below line of code eventually worked for me. onTouch Action_UP was my culprit. Using input.setText(null); did the same effect I wanted and preserved my sanity...

```
    enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String code = input.getText().toString();
            if (code.equals("123456") && index < array_image.size()) {
                array_image.get(index).setImageResource(R.drawable.punch_front);
                index++;
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Awarded " + index + " new punch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                input.setText(null);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, just use a for-loop.

Comment: I've tried that to no avail.

Comment: [The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Comment: *"I've tried that to no avail."* - show us what you've tried.

Comment: @AustinLazarus You need to explicitly say in your question what you've tried and what didn't work. You almost definitely need a for-loop for this so you must have been using it incorrectly.

Comment: I've tried this both:



for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{

if (code.equals("123456"))
{
   array_image.get(i).setImageResource(R.drawable.punch_front);
   Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Awarded 1 new punch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

}


int i = 0;
while (i < i)
{
   array_image.get(i).setImageResource(R.drawable.punch_front);
   Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Awarded 1 new punch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
i++;
}

Which, if I am not mistaken does the same thing.

Comment: @AustinLazarus Don't try to cram code into a comment. Update your question.

Comment: Edit your question. Do not show us what you've done in the comments.

Comment: `while (i < i)`??? what do you think this means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I seem to have misunderstood your question. It looks as if you want to have the image appear only once per fire event.

Doing this would require you do two things.

1. Keep count of the index at which you'll be changing.
2. Increment the index after use.

Also, you'll need to insure you do not go out of bounds as well of course.

First create a counter for the index as a member.

```
private int index = 0;
```

Next you'll want to do what you were doing before almost. In your event listener:

```
if(code.equals("123456") && index < array_image.size())
{
    array_image.get(index).setImageResource(R.drawable.punch_front);
    index++;
}
```

This should keep track of the current index, increment its position for the next event, and after you've gone through your items in the array, it shouldn't give you any exception errors when you go out of bounds and try to fire the event again.

Comment: I've also tried this. It shows all elements. I only need to show one at a time.. Also in Android "array_image.length" returns an error so I use "array_image.size()"

Comment: Then you need to track the index in which you are showing, and update that accordingly

Comment: Ok, perhaps I misunderstood. You don't want to iterate through ALL items in your array, right? You only want to show one per event fire? For example, when you swipe down on the "Enter" button, you show one image, swipe again, show the next image, and remain showing the previous image along with it? 

Something to that effect would require you to store the value of the location you're currently indexed at and maintain it throughout. You would need a member variable like `int index = 0` and then every time you want to make a change, you would use `array_image.get(index)` and `index++` after.

Comment: " For example, when you swipe down on the "Enter" button, you show one image, swipe again, show the next image" correct.. @Yoshi_64 how can I implement this in my existing code?

Comment: Will try this and let you know as soon as I get back on... Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Didn't work.. I'm not sure but I believe my "Key_Up" event has something to do with getting some proper result out of this...

Comment: Perhaps, one thing you could try is remove the `onTouchListener` and try a `onClickListener` instead. You're using an image button, but unless you want the image button to have motion inputs like swiping it down, left, right, etc., you could use an `onClickListener` in its place. Would you like to try that?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick responses bro "Yoshi_64" you saved my life ...